# Не отображается форма в django

Tags: python, django, form

**Django 2.0**

Помогите разобраться, уже кучу времени убил... Вроде всё делаю правильно, а в отображении только кнопка 'отправить', без самой формы.

**urls.py**

```
path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from sh.forms import NameForm

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = NameForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          blog_item = form.save()
          blog_item.save()
    else:
       form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'sh/index.html', {'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```
 class Name(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
 from django import forms
 from .models import Name

 class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ['name']
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить {{form}} на {{ form.as_p }}

Comment: пробывал не помогло, вообще очень странно. сработало только явное указание в forms.py как здесь https://github.com/iyougeen/Add-Attributes-to-form-fields/blob/master/project/blog/forms.py

Спасибо что отозвались

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли в index.html дать форме функцию as

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_ul }}
  <input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```